# How to include a link of the Custom report in email in exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I am new to marketing cloud. I have a scenario that  i want  to include Link in the Email on clicking of the link i want to see the number of emails sent in the last 7 days and the % that are opening, clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build a Cloud Page and on the cloud page you will using AMPScript to build your dashboard/report stats. (You will likely want to process the stats and calculations first using SQL and store the results in a Data Extension and then print the DE results on the cloud page)

You then insert the link of the Cloud Page into your email. However you need to consider how you might secure your Cloud Page as it's a public accessible URL so you would have it open on the internet.

You could alternatively automate Reports in Marketing Cloud and attach the CSV to the send